# Are both of these sentences grammatically correct? (stem+に+行く vs て+行く)

Tags: grammar, translation, formality

These are the sentences:

> ユニオンへサンドイッチを買いに行きました。
>
> ユニオンへサンドイッチを買って行った。

Are they both grammatically correct?  Also do they both mean the same thing, which by my translation is "I went to the union and bought a sandwich."

Do they only differ in their formality with the second sentence being more casual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ユニオン(or [生協]{せいきょう}?/大学生協?)へサンドイッチを買いに行きました。

sounds fine to me. It literally translates to "I went to the union to buy a sandwich."
Its casual version would be:

> ユニオンへサンドイッチを買いに行った。

---

Your second sentence;

> ユニオンへサンドイッチを買って行った。

sounds a bit awkward to me. It sounds to me like "I bought a sandwich and went to the union." (parsed as ユニオンへ（サンドイッチを買って）行った。>> サンドイッチを買って、ユニオンへ行った might sound more natural but it also means "I bought a sandwich, and went to the union".)

買いに行った is like "went to buy" whereas 買って行った is like "bought and went".

As a side note,

> ユニオン**で**サンドイッチを買って行った。(へ-->で)

would be "I bought a sandwich at the union and went (somewhere)"; "I bought a sandwich at the union on the way (to somewhere)"

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing apples with oranges. Let me compare

> サンドイッチを買ってきた。
>   サンドイッチを買いにきた。

instead and hopefully this answers your question.

The first construction means that one action happens after the other. You bought a sandwich and came (home).

The second construction means that you performed the second action to achieve the first. You came to buy a sandwich.

Both sentences can be stated in the polite form, without any change in content:

> サンドイッチを買ってきました。
>   サンドイッチを買いにきました。